# Does Lightroom 5 allow nested conditions for smart collections?

Tags: lightroom

The Lightroom 5 Smart Collections interface allows a number of conditions to be specified, and the user can choose between whether "any" or "all" of the conditions must match.

Is there any way to nest conditions so as to say, show an image

- If A is true
- AND if ANY of B, C, or D are also true

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do nested conditions.

When in the window for defining a smart collection, hold down the Alt (Windows) or Option (OSX) key, and the + button on the right for adding conditions will turn into a # button. Click it, and you can create nested conditions.

Comment: Perfect, thank you! Would be lovely if such things were documented... ;-)

Comment: @SimonW [It _is_ documented in the help](https://helpx.adobe.com/lightroom/help/photo-collections.html#work_with_smart_collections) (scroll down to point 6). But the trick is finding it. I do, however, have a leg up as a professional technical writer and know how the sausages are made. :)

Comment: Huh, so it is! Thing is, it so badly lacks discoverability - ie there's no indication in the UI - that I never even thought to look in the help! My bad. And, of course there's the general principle for Adobe UI of "alt-click everything to see what might happen"...

Comment: @SimonW. Huh. Apparently it's also how you nest conditions in iTunes Smart Lists. :) Maybe it's just an OSX thang.